# Как выбрать первый айтем ListView визуально?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Привет. Нужно, чтобы, к примеру, при срабатывании какого-либо события (допустим, *x*) в ListView визуально выделялся первый или указанный по ID айтем, будто на него нажали мышкой. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

**XAML**

```
<Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="true">
  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
 </Trigger>
```

**C#**

```
ListView.SelectedIndex = *id_айтема*;
```